# How can I replace certain characters in a string?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm relatively new to python(3.5.2) and I'd love some help with my assignment on lists& strings.
I am required to write a code that replaces: e and E with 3, a and A with 4, i and I with 1, o and O with 0 in any given string. Here is my attempt:

```
s = input("Enter a string: ")

leet = {'a':'4','e':'3','i':'1','o':'0','A':'4','E':'3','I':'1','O':'0'}

for character in s:
    if character == leet.keys():
        str.replace(leet.keys(),leet.values())

print(s)
```

This code does not yield any satisfying results for me, I'm wondering if I can use the str.replace method or is there any easier way of doing this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace()` method is good. But you use it wrong. Remember that `leet.keys()` will return a list of all keys in the dictionary. So I suggest this:

```
s = input("Enter a string: ")

leet = {'a': '4', 'e': '3', 'i': '1', 'o': '0', 'A': '4', 'E': '3', 'I': '1', 'O': '0'}

for k, v in leet.items(): #iterating through dictionary (not string)
    s = s.replace(k, v)

print(s)
```

Comment: You will likely run into problems with replacement order using a method like this...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not sure why it is a problem. Order of replacing does not matter.

Comment: Not in a trivial example like this it doesn't, but imagine a substitution cypher. Also generating all of the intermediate strings is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: Performance is not at is best here. You're creating a new string each time something is replaced.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think it is a bit different task. Agree about inefficiency. Another answer is better. But it looks like OP is new to python. So my solution is easier to understand.

Answer (score 5):

you can do that in one line using a generator comprehension converted to a string using `str.join` (Using `dict.get` with defaults to the input character if not found in dictionary):

```
s = "a string Entered"

leet = {'a':'4','e':'3','i':'1','o':'0','A':'4','E':'3','I':'1','O':'0'}

crypted = "".join(leet.get(k,k) for k in s)

print(crypted)
```

result:

```
4 str1ng 3nt3r3d
```

Comment: Could you tell me what the third line of code is doing? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can simplify the leet dict using only lower case: `leet = {'a':'4','e':'3','i':'1','o':'0'}`. Then build the result with: `crypted = "".join(leet.get(k.lower(),k) for k in s)`.

Comment: @Frodon you're right. simpler but maybe a tad slower because you have to create an extra string because of `lower()`. Maybe it would be better to define `leet` like you did and update it with uppercases, so you don't have to `lower` all the letters.

Comment: @chloedonohoe A comprehension list is built using corresponding value of the dict for each letter in input string. If the letter is not found, the original letter is used. The resulting string is built by joining each element of the list.